# Why is the following regex only excluding the first letter of words?

Tags: regex

I want the regex to exclude some words. Something like this:

```
(?!\bhe\b|\bit\b)\w+
```

However, it's only excluding the first letters of these words. In this case, `h` and `i`.

[image]

Why is this and how to fix it?

https://regexr.com/5gjto

Comment: The assertion is true after the `h` or `i` Did you mean like this? `\b(?!he\b|it\b)\w+` https://regex101.com/r/eWVfVc/1

Comment: @That worked. Thanks. Could you post this as an answer with an explanation?

Answer (score 3):

The positive lookahead is not anchored, and will test the assertion before `h` and `e`. The first time it is false, but then it will test the assertion again on the position after the `h` and before the `e`

Now the assertion is true as there is not `he` directly to the right at that position, and it will match 1 or more word characters, being the  the `e`

Placing the `\b` before matching a word char makes sure the lookahead is triggered after first encountering a word boundary.

This way the assertion will not run between `h` and `e` because the word boundary will not match.

```
\b(?!he\b|it\b)\w+
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53c2Cq/1)

Comment: I think just putting a `\b` after the `)` works too.

Comment: @alexchenco That would also work indeed, but placing the `\b` before it would prevent running the lookahead on every position (after matching word characters)

Comment: @alexchenco Did the answer help solving the question?